# Natural deduction proof $(p→¬p ) ⊢ (p→r)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm just learning natural deduction and I'm struggling how to prove $(p→¬p ) ⊢ (p→r)$ properly. Especially I'm wondering what to get $r$ to the implication.

Premise: $(p→¬p)$

Assume: $p$

Eliminate $→$ from 1 to 2: $¬p$

this is what I have got done so far but where do I get the r so that I get the implication $(p→r)$ at the end?

Here are the rules I'm using for $→$ and $¬$:

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have derived a contradiction: $p, \lnot p$.

Apply [$(\lnot \text E)$](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4): $\dfrac { \varphi \ \ \ \lnot \varphi }{\bot}$, to get $\bot$, followed by [$(\bot \text E)$](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4): $\dfrac {\bot}{\varphi}$, to get

> $r$.

If the symbol $\bot$ is missing, you may use the [Ex falso rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation):

> $\dfrac { \varphi \ \ \ \lnot \varphi }{\psi}.$

---

With the rules you have listed, the proof is quite convoluted:

1. $(p \to \lnot p)$ --- premise
2. $p$ --- assumed [a]
3. $\lnot r$ --- assumed [b]
4. $\lnot p$ --- from 1) and 2) by $\to$-elim
5. $p \land \lnot p$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\land$-intro
6. $\lnot \lnot r$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [b]
7. $r$ --- from 6) by $\lnot \lnot$-elim

> 8. $(p \to r)$ --- from 2) and 7), discharging [a].

Comment: But how can I express it without using $⊥$?

Comment: @mathematicsclass23 - It depends on the inference rules used in your system. Can you edit your question to add the rules for $\to$ and $\lnot$?

Answer (score 3):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{
1. P \rightarrow \neg P \qquad \quad Assumption}{
\fitch{
2. P \qquad \quad \qquad Assumption}{
\fitch{
3. \neg R \qquad \quad \quad Assumption}{
4. \neg P \qquad \to \ Elim \ 1,2\\
5. P \land \neg P \qquad  \land \ Intro \ 2,4
} \\
6. \neg \neg R \qquad \quad \neg \ Intro \ 3-5\\
7. R \qquad \qquad \neg \ Elim 6}\\
8. P \to R \qquad \to \ Intro \ 2-7 
}$

Answer (score 0):

Given $\neg p$:

Assume: $p$

$\lor$ Intro: $p \lor r$

$\lor $ Elim (from $\neg p$): $r$

$\to$ Intro: $p\to r$.

This is basically the proof for [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).